# Error while installing spree_wallet, spree_marketplace and spree_drop_ship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I was trying to install spree_wallet, spree_drop_ship and spree_marketplace in spree app I am using.

However, there occurred different problems while installing these gems.

1) I could successfully install bundle for gem spree_wallet but while installing `bundle exec rails g spree_wallet:install`  it gives me the error

```
Could not find generator 'spree_wallet:install'. Maybe you meant 'spree:auth:install', 'spree_gateway:install' or 'spree:install'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

2) When I add the spree_marketplace and spree_drop_ship to the gemfile and execute bundle install , it gives me different version conflict errors.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    spree_core (= 3.0.4)

  In Gemfile:
    spree_core (= 3.0.4) ruby

    spree_core (~> 3.0.0) ruby

    spree_core (~> 3.0.0) ruby

    spree_core (>= 0) ruby

    spree_drop_ship (>= 0) ruby depends on
      spree_core (~> 3.1.0.beta) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

3)  Similarly, when I drop the spree_drop_ship from gemfile, spree_marketplace gives the error saying no gem spree_drop_ship found, which I think is necessary for the working of marketplace gem

Is there any workaround to resolve the issues without downgrading the spree from current version 3.0.4 ??

Comment: I was able to install spree_drop_ship using branch 3-0-stable.  `gem 'spree_drop_ship', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship', branch: '3-0-stable' ` but still not able to install spree_marketplace

Comment: When I try to install spree_marketplace , it throws an error `spree_marketplace (>= 0) ruby depends on
      spree_core (~> 2.3.0) ruby`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are struggling with same, I found the solution with adding below gems

```
gem 'spree_drop_ship', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_marketplace', github: 'firman/spree_marketplace'
```

`firman/spree_marketplace` is forked from `spree-contrib/spree_marketplace` and resolves the dependency issue